# hyperledger fabric. Invoke a transaction from behind a corporate http proxy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc, grpc-node

By invoking a transaction as a client, I need to connect to peers and orderer using grpc.

unfortunately, I'm not able to get grpc requests through the http proxy defined in the environment variables "http_proxy" and "https_proxy".

I'm working with the fabric node SDK.

I'm using the library "fabric-client" v1.2 and tried with grpc v 1.6.0 and 1.13.1. Both failed.

For your info, the connection to the CA server (via http) is redirect to the proxy using global-tunnel-ng. It works.

Comment: What values are you setting for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`?  Are you including `http://` as part of the values?

Comment: Yes, I'm setting http://ip:port

Comment: So are you setting `http://ip:port` or just `ip:port`?  As I recall, you need to use the full URL including `http://`

Comment: sorry it is a formatting error I made. I'm setting `http://ip:port`

Comment: Can you try setting `GRPC_TRACE=all` and `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug` ?  You might see something in the logs.  You can try to narrow down the trace results as documented in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md

Comment: Hey Gari, thanks for your help. The problem has been found: the global-tunnel-ng is deleting the process.envs http_proxy after reading it. So grpc got an empty http_proxy. I deactivated the global-tunnel-ng and now it works!

Comment: node_modules\global-tunnel-ng\index.js:
     ` // NB: we do it here to prevent double proxy handling (and for example path change) by us and the `request` module or other sub-dependencies
      delete process.env[key];`

Comment: Ah ... very interesting .... you might want to post a self answer to your question

Comment: Thanks for your help Gari!!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved. It was because of the "global-tunnel-ng" package which is deleting the http_proxy value in process.env after reading it.
A workaround is to delete these lines in node_modules\global-tunnel-ng\index.js:

```
// NB: we do it here to prevent double proxy handling (and for example path change) 
// by us and the request module or other sub-dependencies 
delete process.env[key];
```